# Checking if a form has input elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, submit

I'm developing an application using Yii PHP framework, and I'm using jQuery for form validation. I have a page with a *form* on it which contains *checkboxes* for its input elements.

However these checkboxes are **dynamically created** depending on the entries.

To better understand it, I'm making a crossing matrix, a table basically, having *rows* for feemales and *columns* for males, and defining **checkboxes in the cells where there are intersections**. Literally a crossing matrix for male and female individuals.

However if there are **no males and females** that are defined to be crossed yet, then as for validation, **it should not allow the user to submit.**

My problem is how do I know whether a form has no elements?

And if there are checkbox elements, how can I catch whether or not the user has checked at least one of them?

Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't seem to catch it, the form still submits data, I wonder why:

```
$('#crossingMatrixForm').submit(function() {

       $(":input").each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() === empty()) {
               alert("form empty!");
               return false;
           }
       });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see if at least one checkbox exists in the form and is checked with

```
$('#crossingMatrixForm').submit(function(){    
    if (!$(this).find("input:checked").length) {
        alert("form empty!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you want to disambiguate between "no checkboxes exist" and "at least one exists, but none are checked" you can use `$(this).find(":checkbox")` for the former and `.filter(":checked")` on that for the latter. In both cases, use `.length` to see if at least one control exists:

```
$('#crossingMatrixForm').submit(function(){    
    var checkboxes = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    if (!checkboxes.length) {
        alert("form empty!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!checkboxes.filter(":checked").length) {
        alert("none selected!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i no longer need to disambiguate between the two situations

Answer (score 2):

As per [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):  `empty()` is :

```
Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.
```

So you must use `" "` to compare the string.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows you to test for [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) fields and whether or not any are [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/). So with those in hand you could try the following:

```
$('#crossingMatrixForm').submit(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.find('input:checkbox').length || !$this.find('input:checked').length) {
        alert('Form empty!');
        return false;
    }
});
```